# Doctrine Entity Validation (Setter Method Validation or Event Driven)

Tags: php, oop, validation, model, doctrine-orm

A very interesting subject has arisen today with two points of view.

Using Doctrine Entities

1. Should the validation of the data be done at the point when a setter method is called? I.e. Inside a setFieldName() method, or
2. Should the entity be validated as a whole for valid data [when an event is triggered on an entity](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-validations.html)?

Is there a **normal** or **tried and tested** theory and/or point of view on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "normal"/standard way to go about this - I guess it depends on your needs. I can tell you my point of view:
For me data validation should be done on setters - that is - as soon as possible. This way you cannot have an entity with invalid data set on it and it will save you headaches when you are going to persist.

Try to think of it this way: Let's say you have a car that runs on petrol. You go to the gas station to refill. You have two pumps: petrol and gasoline. Without validation, you would be able to put either type of fuel in there and until you turn the engine on nothing would happen. But when you do, if you put the wrong type of fuel, it would be too late. Boooooooom! Of course entities don't explode.;)

Having said that, sometimes it is not possible to do validation on a single setter because it could be dependent on another property(which has not been yet set). Something like VATID for user entity where property user_type(private|company) has to be available in order to be able to check and force VATID for companies. In this case you'd do some [PrePersist/PreUpdate validation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/validation-of-entities.html).